# Сделать кроссбраузерность. offsetLeft

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, кроссбраузерность

Есть вот такой код. Я пробегаюсь по списку карточек, и записываю их offsetLeft.

```
let indents = [];
for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; ++i) {
   indents.push(-cards[i].offsetLeft)
}
console.log(indents);
```

Однако в explorer 11 получаю другие данные, нежели в Хроме.

Explorer не включает `margin-right`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы это работало одинаково во всех браузерах?

Comment: box-sizing: border-box пробовали?

Comment: Да, здесь именно такой box-sizing